# WordPress: Don't notify admin when user registers or modifies account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-registration

I'm having trouble finding the proper information on going about removing admin email notifications. I've read that disabling these emails will break emails on the user end as well, because a function needs two recipients or is null.

I would like not to have notification emails sent to the admin, when a user registers, changes their password, or changes their email address. Is there a cheetsheet for complete hook anyone could point me to?

Comment: this plugin might be what you're looking for : https://wordpress.org/plugins/manage-notification-emails/

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've been sitting on this one, it's a last resort for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this hook to disable sending notifications for new users

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    remove_action( 'register_new_user',   'wp_send_new_user_notifications'         );
    add_action(    'register_new_user',   'wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications' );
} );

function wpse236122_send_new_user_notifications(  $user_id, $notify = 'user' )
{   
    wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify );    
}
```

`wp_send_new_user_notifications()` is also hooked into these actions:

```
network_site_new_created_user
network_site_users_created_user
network_user_new_created_user
edit_user_created_user
```